# I want to read some part of text from a text file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new here. please guide me if i go wrong somewhere. Also i am new to python programming.
MY question is:- i want to read all the lines but limited columns of a text file in python.
Conside this:-

text.txt

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa   bbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccc ddddddddddddddd
>
> eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee    aaaaaaaaaaaaa ffffffffffffffffffffffffff  ggggggggggggggg
>
> hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
> aaaaaaaaaaaaa
> aaaaaaaaaaa
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

NOte:- it is in tabular form but is not in a table **the text is not the actual text**

Requirement:- I want python to read all lines but only 2 columns and print it

Please help me solve it.!

Here's MY python code snippet for it.!

> myfile = open("output.txt","rt")
>
> for line in myfile:
>
> data =
> myfile.read().replace('\t','')
>
> data2 = open("output2.txt", "w")
>
> data2.write(data)
>
> data2.close()

Comment: Please show your effort (code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split each line according to the whitespace and then take just the first two columns.

A naive solution with regard to memory consumption could look something like this:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f
    lines = f.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        print(' '.join(l.split()[:2]))
```

Comment: Please don‘t encourage people to use readlines like this - it is pointless and can prevent reading large files. One can directly loop over the lines in an open file, and Python will read only a small portion at once.

Comment: how can i count spaces in python.?

Comment: how can i count spaces in python.? like if there are rows and in each row some string is present after 7 spaces and that string is to be replaced by another string.